# Access to Google Fit Activity Data

Tags: android, google-fit

This is a Google Fit app screenshot.

My app don't work for some user if they don't activate this in Google fit app.

Is someone knows how to activate it directly in your app ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the [Google Fit samples on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit) on how they are authorizing their app.

Based on the documentation - [Authorization on Android](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization):

> The authorization flow is the following:
>
> 1. Your app requests a connection, with one or more scopes of access, to the fitness service.
> 2. Google Fit prompts the user to grant your app the required permissions.
> 3. If the user consents, your app can access fitness data of the types defined by the scope.

I think you should implement your error catch when your user didn't activate this in Google fit app like (Activate Required).

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) Thanks!
2) This is the problem. I've already checked this code and I didn't manage to find the code to "generate" this popup...